# Save entity with FK "reuse"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring + Hibernate JPAA.

I have an entity:

```
A
  id (PK)
  Set<B> b;
  otherProps…

B
  id (PK)
  String name; (unique)
  otherProps…
```

and there is a M to M table linking A.id, B.id.

if the user creates an entity:

```
A.id = 0
A.b.id = 0
A.b.Name = "Admin";
```

It saves, but it creates a new entry in the B table. Consider B as a "Roles" table defined by the system, it shouldn't change. So I want it to re-use Admin and auto populate the id. This object comes from a REST api… is it expected in that case for the caller to know the id & name? or should they just be able to populate by id or Name?

How to handle this situation? Or would it be better to get rid of the id and have the name as the PK?

EDIT: to clarify...

User entity
Role entity
UserRole table with User.Id, Role.Id M2M relationship.

Role table contains:
1 User
2 Admin
3 Super User

That is a *fixed* table defined by me. A caller is not allowed to add roles.

So if User1 is a User, then there will be an entry in the M2M table 1,1.

Now, imagine if someone passes in a new user object User2 with Role "User". As it is right now, it creates an entry in Roles id=4 value=User (a duplicate entry) and in the M2M table, it creates a 1,4 where the intended behavior is 1,1 i.e. reuse the existing "User" role.

Basically, I guess it makes sense for a caller to know the user id, but I'm not sure if it makes sense for the caller to know the role id? seems more like they would know the possible roles. Kind of think of it like an enum type behavior?

@Entity
@Table(name="Customers")
public class Customer {

```
@ApiModelProperty(notes="Id of the customer.", required=true, value="100000")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long customerId;
@NotNull
@Size(min=2, max=64)
@ApiModelProperty(notes="First name of the customer.", required=true, value="John")
private String firstName;
@NotNull
@Size(min=2, max=64)
@ApiModelProperty(notes="Last name of the customer.", required=true, value="Smith")
private String lastName;
@ManyToMany(cascade={ CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name="CustomerRoles",
           joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="CustomerId") },
           inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="RoleId") }
)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

public Long getCustomerId() {
    return this.customerId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return new ArrayList<Role>(this.roles);
}
```

@Entity
@Table(name="Roles")
public class Role {

```
@ApiModelProperty(notes="Id of the role.", required=true, value="1")
@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long roleId;
@NotNull
@Size(min=2, max=64)
@ApiModelProperty(notes="Name of the role.", required=true, value="Admin")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Set<Customer> roles = new HashSet<Customer>();

public Long getRoleId() {
    return this.roleId;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to figure out what is happening without complete code.
But in general you should consider following concept:

The entity with `JoinTable` annotation is the **Owner** of relation. It means if you enable `Cascade.Merge` on 'Owner`, adding new records to it, will add another record to intermediate table.

**An Example**

`Role` entity:

```
{
  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "tb_role_privilege",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id"))
    private Set<Privilege> privileges = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and `Privilege` entity:

```
{
      @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
}
```

Here, `Role` is the owner of relation. when you create a role object with `id=0` and fill its list of privileges with `ids=[0 1 2]`, and call `save`, it will insert role record to the `tb_role` and also, it will insert (0,0), (0,1) and (0,2) to intermediate table `tb_role_privilege`, **but it does not insert anything into `tb_privilege`**. so you need to insert privilege records to `tb_privilege` before inserting role record.

It is a good and simple approach for `m2m` relationships. If it doesn't satisfy your scenario, provide your code with more information.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question a bit, does that clear things up? If not, I will post the entities.

Comment: @SledgeHammer your scenario is the exact scenario i explained. Make the user entity the owner and add cascade.merge on it. Base on example, role entity is your user, and privilege entity is your role

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post to show my 2 entities. If I match the ENTIRE role entity exactly 1,Admin then it works. If I put in 0,Admin, then it throws a FK constraint exception. I think where the difference is, is that my Id's start at 1 for the roles and that I only want to pass in the NAME (and match the behavior of Customer where a 0 will auto fill in the correct id in the response). Or in this scenario is it expected to pass in the id too? This isn't an issue for Customer since that is a generated id.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I need to query the Roles table by Name and patch the ids in the request manually or if there is some hibernate trick for that.

Comment: @SledgeHammer fetching the role record by name and pass its id is a standard and good way. there's no need for tricks or workarounds